# Display cases in contact summary tab in reverse order (ORDER BY id DESC)

Tags: civicase, civicrm-home, contact-view

I'm trying to display cases in reverse order in contact summary Cases Tab. I tried using hook called `civicrm_searchColumns( $objectName, &$headers,  &$values, &$selector )`

and changed the values using `$values = array_reverse($values);`. but some contacts got more than 100 cases split into different pages. using this hook I cant get cases in `ORDER BY id DESC` order.

I checked relevant php file `CRM_Case_Page_Tab`. Its using controller in browse function like below

```
  public function browse() {

    $controller = new CRM_Core_Controller_Simple('CRM_Case_Form_Search', ts('Case'), CRM_Core_Action::BROWSE);
    $controller->setEmbedded(TRUE);
    $controller->reset();
    $controller->set('limit', 20);
    $controller->set('force', 1);
    $controller->set('context', 'case');
    $controller->process();
    $controller->run();
```

Can anyone suggest me is there any option to add sort by to this controller object for case id in descending order?

or where to add this order by case id to the actual query?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

I found quick hack to add sort in `CRM_Case_Selector_Search` class file. Though its not good practice to touch core, I could not find better option to get around this problem

```
  public function &getRows($action, $offset, $rowCount, $sort, $output = NULL) {
       //adding sort here for descending
        $sort->_vars[1] = array('name'=>'case_id',
                                'direction'=>CRM_Utils_Sort::DESCENDING,
                                'title'=>ts('Case ID')
                               );
```